# Display text properly within ellipse

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.drawing

I need to properly display text within a drawn ellipse in c#, currently here is what i am using.

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, base.Font, new SolidBrush(_NormalColorA), this.ClientRectangle, GetStringFormat(this.TextAlign));
```

The GetStringFormat function

```
static internal StringFormat GetStringFormat(ContentAlignment ctrlalign)
        {
            StringFormat strFormat = new StringFormat();
            switch (ctrlalign)
            {
                case ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
                    strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    break;
                case ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
                    strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                    break;
                case ContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                    strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                    break;
                case ContentAlignment.TopCenter:
                    strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                    strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    break;
                case ContentAlignment.TopLeft:
                    strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                    strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                    break;
                case ContentAlignment.TopRight:
                    strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                    strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                    break;
                case ContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
                    strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                    strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    break;
                case ContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
                    strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                    strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                    break;
                case ContentAlignment.BottomRight:
                    strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                    strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                    break;
            }

            strFormat.HotkeyPrefix = System.Drawing.Text.HotkeyPrefix.None;

            return strFormat;
        }
```

In the picture bellow, you can see the problem and the expected, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: When the rectangle is outside (tangent, really) your ellipse then there's exactly one position it can be in.  If you want the rectangle inside, though, there are many possible rectangles that could fit with varying widths/heights.  You'll need to constrain the solution somehow in order to calculate the correct coordinates.

Comment: From the design, it looks like you want to place your text on the 1) the intersection of the outer rectangle diagonals with the ellipse 2) the ellipse X axis on `((0, [Ellipse height] /2), ([Ellipse width], [Ellipse height] /2))`. The top-left point [P].X is ~1/6 the outer rectangle width, [P].Y is ~1/6 the outer rectangle height. So, [P] = `(outer.width / 6, outer.height / 6)` (+ the Offset(X, Y) in the drawing). The Inner rectangle Size is then `(outer.width - [P].X * 2, outer.height - [P].Y * 2)`. The Inner Rectangle is then `Offset.X + [P].X, Offset.Y + [P].Y, Inner.Width, Inner.Height`.

Comment: @RogerN the rectangle that has the best fit or largest that can fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an ellipse is geometrically equivalent to a circle that has been scaled linearly, and since your major and minor axes are always aligned with the X and Y axes, the inner rectangle which maximizes the available area for your text can be found by simply multiplying the total width and height of your ellipse by sqrt(2)/2.

Given a rectangle describing your ellipse, this function ought to calculate the correct layout rectangle for your text:

```
private static RectangleF GetEllipseInnerRect(RectangleF ellipse) {
    const float HalfSqrt2 = 0.707107f;
    var innerSize = new SizeF(ellipse.Width * HalfSqrt2, ellipse.Height * HalfSqrt2);
    return new RectangleF(
        ellipse.Left + 0.5f * (ellipse.Width - innerSize.Width),
        ellipse.Top + 0.5f * (ellipse.Height - innerSize.Height),
        innerSize.Width,
        innerSize.Height);
}
```